# How does postDelayed work?

Tags: android, animation, delay

I generate a number of `ImageViews` in the same location. Now, I want to apply an animation to each of these images, but not in the same time.

Let's say I want the first image to start moving at sec 0, then image2 at sec 2 and so on.

I have the images in an array, `imb_items[]`.

if i use this:

```
for(int j = 0; j < i; j++) {
    final int finalJ = j;
    new android.os.Handler().postDelayed(
        new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                imb_items[finalJ].startAnimation(translateAnim);
                Log.i("tag", "This'll run 5000 milliseconds later");
            }
        },
        5000*finalJ
    );
}
```

When the second image start moving, the first one stops and disappears.

How could I solve this?  I would like all the images to continue their movement.

Comment: what's the duration of animation?

Comment: the animation has 8.5 seconds

Comment: And the images are all visible, and in the same location. I want them to start moving, sequentially, one after another, until they all move 8.5 seconds

Comment: what does `5000*finalJ` mean?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it's not working because you're trying to interact a for-loop with the delayed execution of something else. It doesn't work like this.

but why not just set the start offset of the animation?
https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/animation/Animation.html#setStartOffset(long)

have an array of ImageView and an array of Animation (one animation for each ImageView)

```
for(int j=0; j<i;j++) {
   translateAnim[j].setStartOffset(5000*j);
   imb_items[j].startAnimation(translateAnim[j]);
}
```